# Angular 13 routing failed, can't extract property when return value as observable

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

The parent component passed a id number to my child component, then I want to use this id to get my  value which has several properties. I wrote a service to find the certain  by returning observable. Then I want to show this observable's id in my html, but it failed and says
**TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Observable'.**

my html code

```
   <h2>{{dog$.id}}</h2>
```

the component code

```
 dog$!: Observable<Dog>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dog$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.service.getDog(params.get('id')!))
    ); 
  }
```

the service code:

```
  getDog(id: number | string): Observable<Dog> {
      const dog = DOGS.find(result => result.id === id)!;
      return of(dog);
  }
```

can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show an observable to html. In order to show the id of the observable you should try something like that `{{(dog$ | async)?.id}}` with async pipe. Also you maybe have to modify your `switchMap` in order to return the observable.

```
switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  return this.service.getDog(params.get('id')!))
```

Othewise your dog observable wont get the value from `switchMap`

Comment: Hi tufonas, I added one line in my html to show the id like this ``` <div> {{ (dog$ | async)?.id}}</div>```, but nothing comes up

Comment: Have you tried the return on switchMap? Do you get the same error?

Comment: yes, I add it like this `this.dog$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        {return this.service.getDog(params.get('id')!)})
    ); `

Comment: Instead of trying to show it directly to html, why dont you try to subcribe to this observable and check the value that will be returned